# Export Illustrator layers to Photoshop Smart Objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to export the layers of my illustrator document into photoshop, but the only way to do so is one by one copy and pasting...are there any ways to mass export these layers while still preserving them as smart objects?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. There's no way to transfer AI layers to Photoshop Smart Objects other than copy/pasting one by one.